# Async/await - waiting for the return of data?

Tags: javascript

I have a fetch method:

```
async fetch {
    return await axios.get('/api/users');
}
```

This is called:

```
let data = this.fetch();
console.log(data);
```

But the log is a `promise` - how can I get the log after the method call to log the data and not the promise, I thought async/await would wait for the promise to resolve?

Comment: I think the fetch "method" is missing some syntax. Also I think the async/await is unnecessary as it returns a promise. Consider using `let data = await this.fetch()`?

Comment: An [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) always returns a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async fetch {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/users');
    return await res.data;
}
```

Comment: I don't think axios returns a json method https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema

Comment: @evolutionxbox, you are right. I have updated the code. Thank you for checking

Comment: This is near on what I have in my example... and still returns a promise

Comment: @panthro it will always return a promise. To get the result, either await the fetch call inside an async function, or use `.then`.

Comment: Ok, so I will need to console.log() inside the fetch or use then, that's the answer I'm looking for - thanks!

Comment: @panthro, you can add another `await` keyword in the last line. Please check the updated code

Comment: @panthro it doesn't need to be in the fetch, no. Try `console.log(await fetch())` or `fetch().then(x => console.log(x))`

Comment: An `async` function will always return a Promise, putting await after the `return` keyword won't change this.

Comment: You are right @NickParsons

Answer (score 0):

To read the data from a promise you must wait for it to finish executing. You can use the `.then()` function to log the data.

```js
let data = this.fetch();

data.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

You can read further about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: While this is correct, the OP is asking about `Async/await` in the title.